# Play Framework - ErrorHandler is not being invoked

Tags: java, error-handling, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm facing an issue in **Play framework (2.6)** while trying to handle an exception using the **HttpErrorHandler** mechanism in a specific scenario.

I have a simple **ErrorHandler** in the root package:

```
import play.Logger;
import play.http.HttpErrorHandler;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.Results;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class ErrorHandler implements HttpErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> onClientError(Http.RequestHeader request, int statusCode, String message) {
        Logger.error("client error");
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Results.status(statusCode, "A client error occurred: " + message));
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> onServerError(Http.RequestHeader request, Throwable exception) {
        Logger.error("server error");

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
                Results.internalServerError("A server error occurred: " + exception.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

I created a custom controller to handle the **assets**:

```
package controllers;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import play.api.mvc.Action;
import play.api.mvc.AnyContent;
import play.mvc.Controller;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class AssetsCustomController extends Controller {

    private final Assets assets;

    @Inject
    public AssetsCustomController(Assets assets) {
        this.assets = assets;
    }

    public Action<AnyContent> at(String path, String file) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return assets.at(path, file, false);
    }
}
```

I've checked the **ErrorHandler** and is working fine for all the cases except when the exception is thrown from this method in **AssetsCustomController**:

```
public Action<AnyContent> at(String path, String file) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return assets.at(path, file, false);
    }
```

For instance, when the **IllegalArgumentException** is thrown, my **ErrorHandler** is ignored and Play uses his native error handler. Here is the stacktrace:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: null]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:255)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:182)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler$.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:286)
        at play.core.server.Server.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala:53)
        at play.core.server.Server.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:83)
        at play.core.server.Server.getHandlerFor$(Server.scala:49)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.getHandlerFor(AkkaHttpServer.scala:42)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.getHandler(AkkaHttpServer.scala:215)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:195)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$3(AkkaHttpServer.scala:107)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at controllers.AssetsCustomController.at(AssetsCustomController.java:20)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$10(Routes.scala:183)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$6$$anon$7.call(HandlerInvoker.scala:61)
        at play.core.routing.GeneratedRouter$$anon$2.call(GeneratedRouter.scala:251)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$9(Routes.scala:183)
        at play.core.routing.GeneratedRouter.$anonfun$call$5(GeneratedRouter.scala:99)
        at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:118)
        at play.core.routing.GeneratedRouter.call(GeneratedRouter.scala:99)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.applyOrElse(Routes.scala:182)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.applyOrElse(Routes.scala:154)
```

**[SOLUTION]**
Thanks to the answer **Flo354**, I was able to solve the problem and the **AssetsCustomController** is like this:

```
package controllers;

import akka.stream.Materializer;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class AssetsCustomController extends Controller {

    private final Assets assets;
    private final Materializer materializer;

    @Inject
    public AssetsCustomController(Materializer materializer, Assets assets) {
        this.materializer = materializer;
        this.assets = assets;
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> at(String path, String file) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return assets.at(path, file, false).asJava().apply(request()).run(materializer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Action<AnyContent>` is part of the Scala API, which means it does not use the Java part.

Your Custom error handler apply only to Java sources. Look at your stack trace

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: null]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:255)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:182)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler$.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:286)
....
```

You can see that it's scala when there is `play.api.something`

You can workaround this by sending back a `CompletionStage<Result>`

```
public CompletionStage<Result> test(String path, String file) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    return assets.at(path, file, false).asJava().apply(request()).run(materializer);
}
```

And in your controller, don't forget to inject an instance of `akka.stream.Materializer`

Hope it will help!

Comment: I was able to call the ErrorHandler when some exception is thrown. However, in the success flow is rendering the content in the console instead of browser. This behavior is due CompletionStage<Result>? Do you know how can I workaround this problem? Follow a [printscreen](https://snag.gy/fi20zs.jpg) to show how the browser is treating the call.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my end... Could you provide a simple git project which reproduces the issue so I could look at it?

Comment: Sorry for delay. I've checked here and I've found the problem that was happening. Now it is working fine. Thanks!